# Wordpress | put username in the end of the link

Tags: wordpress

I have this code.

```html
return '<a href="http://test.com/members/">'.$username.'</a>';
```

I would like to put the username in the end of the link. So that link redirects to X user. Something like this, i hope you understand what im trying to do. So i just would like to know the correct code for it from you pros.

```html
return '<a href="http://test.com/members/<php .$username. php>">'.$username.'</a>';
```

Comment: The redirect logic should be placed in the template the link is directed to using : wp_get_current_user(), not appending to the link.

Comment: Read about [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: Well i need it that way. Not current_user.
Well i understand the strucuture but im not a coder so for me it looks like (/¤%()¤%=)#¤ when im trying to read code.

Comment: If your content is accessible to the public with just the link, make sure at least there's no private user info on that page or this is seriously a problem. And you are asking an XY question probably: You may want to describe what you are trying to accomplish as an end goal rather than asking about an attempted solution since you are not familiar with coding at all it seems.

Comment: Well its simple. When i click a user i want to go to his buddypress page. This is the solution i have and i know it works. Just need the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
return '<a href="http://test.com/members/'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a>';
```

Comment: That was the the first and only solution i tryied. The link redirection became this: http://test.com/members/%3Cspan%20class=